# WHM Email Stuck in Manager Queue after Cloudflare Setup

Tags: email, queue, cloudflare, whm

My WHM server seems to be storing all its email in the queue manager, I get the following errors from EXIM

LOG: MAIN
  cwd=/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot 4 args: /usr/sbin/exim -v -M 1ZHBnT-0003rU-0v
delivering 1ZHBnT-0003rU-0v
LOG: MAIN
  SMTP connection identification H=localhost A=::1 P=60184 M=1ZHBnT-0003rU-0v U=root ID=0 S=root B=authenticated_local_user
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.70.27]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
  H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.70.27] Connection timed out
Connecting to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.204.27]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
  H=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.204.27] Connection timed out
Connecting to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.141.27]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
  H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.141.27] Connection timed out
Connecting to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.190.27]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
  H=alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.190.27] Connection timed out

Port 25 is open.

Answer (score 1):

I think your server mail IP is blocked on gmail server and due to that you are getting this issues. May be your one of the user is sending spam mails from your server and that is the reason your server IP is blocked. You can check your mail server IP status through http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx URL.